# Can a script be set as a parameter of a function in c# Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the same function - Attack() in two scripts and i would like to inherit them from a class which has this function. So my question is can a script be set as a parameter of a function in c# Unity?

```
public void Attack()
{
    _animator.SetTrigger("Attack");

    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(_attackPoint.position, _attackRange, _enemyLayer);
    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        enemy.GetComponent<PlayerAnimator>().TakeDamage(_attackDamage);// in second script there is <EnemyAnimator>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's OOP basics - In such a case you have mainly two options:

You should have

- an interface if it is only about having the same method signatures but completely different behavior

  ```
  public interface IDamageable
  {
      void TakeDamage(float damage);
  }
  ```

  And then

  ```
  public class PlayerAnimator : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable
  {
      public void TakeDamage(float damage)
      {
          Debug.Log($"I'm a player and do a certain thing when I take {damage} amount of damage");
      }
  }

  public class EnemyAnimator : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable
  {
      public void TakeDamage(float damage)
      {
          Debug.Log($"I'm an enmy and do something completely different when I take {damage} amount of damage");
      }
  }
  ```
- go through inheritance and have a common parent class which already implements common behavior and can then be extended - if needed at all

  ```
  // Careful with this naming in that case!
  public class Damageable : MonoBehaviour
  {
      virtual void TakeDamage(float damage)
      {
          Debug.Log("This is the common default behavior for my inheritors - except the overwrite or extend it");
      }
  }
  ```

  and

  ```
  public class PlayerAnimator : Damageable 
  {
      public override void TakeDamage(float damage)
      {
          // First call the default implementation
          base.TakeDamage(damage);

          Debug.Log($"I'm a player and do some additional stuff");
      }
  }

  public class EnemyAnimator : Damageable 
  {
      public override void TakeDamage(float damage)
      {
          Debug.Log($"I'm an enmy and decided to not do the default thing but something completely different");
      }
  }
  ```

  Here if you don't need any different behavior between `EnemyAnimator` and `PlayerAnimator` the answer would be easy: Just stick to a single class then!

And then I would go

```
public void Attack()
{
    _animator.SetTrigger("Attack");

    var hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(_attackPoint.position, _attackRange, _enemyLayer);

    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        // OPTION A
        if(enemy.TryGetComponent<IDamagable>(out var damageable))
        // or OPTION B
        //if(enemy.TryGetComponent<Damagable>(out var damageable))
        {
            damageable.TakeDamage(_attackDamage)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> can a script be set as a parameter of a function in c# Unity?

The answer is yes, but with some constraints. If you want to use the `GetComponent<ScriptParameter>()` you would need do do something like [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time):

To pass a `Type` as a parameter you could make your method accept a generic type and constrain it to your base class.

```cs
public static class AttackManager
{
    public static void Attack<T>(Animator attackerAnimator, Transform attacker, float attackRange, float damage, int targetLayer) where T : AnimatorBase
    {
        attackerAnimator.SetTrigger("Attack");

        Collider2D[] hitTargets = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attacker.position, attackRange, targetLayer);
        foreach (Collider2D target in hitTargets)
        {
            target.GetComponent<T>().TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

*Notice I transformed your `Attack()` method into a generic static method that takes attacker and target info*

The type assumes your `PlayerAnimator` and `EnemyAnimator` derive from a base class for example:

```cs
//I made it abstract you could do it other ways, such as mentioned in @derHugo answer
public abstract class AnimatorBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void TakeDamage(float damage);
}
```

```cs
public class PlayerAnimator : AnimatorBase
{
    public override void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("player took damage");
    }
}
```

```cs
public class EnemyAnimator : AnimatorBase
{
    public override void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy took damage");
    }
}
```

Now you would just call the function as:

```cs
AttackManager.Attack<PlayerAnimator>(attackerAnimator: animator,
                                     attacker: enemy,
                                     attackRange: range,
                                     damage: _attackDamage,
                                     targetLayer: LayerMask.GetMask("player"));
```

or

```cs
AttackManager.Attack<EnemyAnimator>(attackerAnimator: animator,
                                     attacker: player,
                                     attackRange: range,
                                     damage: _attackDamage,
                                     targetLayer: LayerMask.GetMask("enemy"));
```

Comment: imho the `AttackManager` is a bit of overkill. For instance why is that a `MonoBehaviour` at all? It doesn't use any of the message methods and it is probably unnecessary to attach it to a specific `GameObject`. The generic method with type limit is nice to have .. but if you suggest a common base class anyway you would rather go through it directly  - which I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75626940/7111561) ;) - there is no need/desire by OP to explicitly type in the generic type

Comment: I explained that there were good answers that probably would be the way to go, I only showed how to pass in the script as the OP asked. regarding the `MonoBehaviour `  it was default I didn't bother removing because I dont have the logic.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `AttackManager` is something you introduced as a `MonoBehaviour` and that it doesn't need to be on .. can just be a static helper method .. thogh the way you introduced it it also makes no sense .. currently it would look for a `AnimatorBase` component on the same object the `AttackManager` is attached to ...

Comment: yes I oversaw that bit from the attack manager, thanks to point out.

Comment: I changed the answer to fix the oversight and I took in consideration the what you mentioned about `MonoBehaviour`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, a script can be set as a parameter of a function in unity c#. All you need to do is first of all the script's name, followed by what you want to call it. Like this :

```
public void Attack(EnemyAnimator enemyAnimator)
{
    _animator.SetTrigger("Attack");

    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = 
    Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(_attackPoint.position, _attackRange, 
    _enemyLayer);
    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        enemy.GetComponent<PlayerAnimator>().TakeDamage(_attackDamage);
    }
}
```

Comment: If EnemyAnimator is not the script's name, switch it out to be the script's name, remember, capitalization matters.

Comment: i mean can a not specific script be a parametr like:

`public void Attack(Script scriptname)
{
       enemy.GetComponent<scriptname>().TakeDamage(_attackDamage);
}`

Comment: oh no sorry i dont think so

Comment: but you can do scriptable objects

Comment: @Kuji I think there is a bit of a misunderstanding of what you want to achieve ... If you do `public void Attack(Script scriptname)` the `scriptname` is just the name of your parameter. Within there is already a reference to an instance of the **type** `Script` => You actually would rather want to use `enemy.GetComponent<Script>()` then. And yes there is a non-generic version of `GetComponent(System.Type type)` where you can pass in a dynamic type ... I don't think it is what you are looking for though ;) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75626940/7111561)

Comment: @derHugo i call from script EnemyAnimator function of script PlayerAnimator, and i such thing i do in PlayerAnimator script, so i wanted to not repeat similar functioins somehow